# Create algorithm to add values of primary diagonals in a java 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am new to this forum so please forgive me if this has been covered already.
I have an assignment for class which covers the following:

- Create a 10 x 10 two dimensional array of int data type
- Load each index location in the array with the sum of it's row + column
- Create and algorithm that will add all the values in the diagonal indexes 
  from 0,0 to 9,9 and print the total
- Create and algorithm that will add all the values in the diagonal indexes 
  from 0,9 to 9,0 and print the total
- Print the addition of both diagonals

I had no problem creating the array but I am stumped as to how to add the primary diagonals.  It tried a solution that I saw on another post to this sit but I kept getting for the Return total value stating that it could not be type void.  Anyway, here is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class AddDiagonals2
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    int[][] numbers = new int [10][10];
        row = 0; col = 0;
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++)
     {
         for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++)
         {
             numbers[row][col] = row + col;
             out.print (numbers[row][col] +"\t");
         }
         out.println();
    }
```

Here is what I tried to add from the other post to calculate the diagonals but it didn't work.

```
        for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++)
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + numbers[row][row];
        }
        row = numbers.length-1;
        for (col = 0; col < numbers.length; col++)
        {
            if (col >= 0)
        {
             sum2 = sum2 + numbers[row][col];
             col--;
        }
        out.println ("Sum of the Diagonal elements are : " + sum1 + " and " + sum2);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to add the ints at locations [0][0], then [1][1], then [2][2]... see the pattern? Second part is [0][9], [1][8], [2][7]... also a simple pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum2 = sum2 + numbers[row][col];
```

Shouldn't it be [col][col]? I only skimmed it, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (col = 0; col < numbers.length; col++)
        {
            if (col >= 0)
        {
             sum2 = sum2 + numbers[row][col];
             col--;
        }
```

You are incrementing col in the loop header and decrementing it again in the loop body. You want col to go from 0 to 9 and row to go from 9 to 0 (or the other way around). Since you start col at 0 and row at `numbers.length-1`, increment col and decrement row once per loop.
Note that you can actually do this in the for loop header, using a `,` to separate statements:

```
for (col = 0; col < numbers.length; col++, row--)
```